# What do mathematicians mean by "push through a proof"?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, terminology

I sometimes hear mathematicians say they want to "push through a proof". What does this mean?

Comment: Haven't heard this expression in math. In English "to push through" something means to work one's way through something. So I guess it has to do with working through the proof, checking the details and what not. I may be mistaken.

Comment: Alternatively, laws are being "pushed through" legislation. So it could refer to publishing some result in a journal and getting it accepted. It's a bit of a reach.

Comment: @conifold What about turning your nice comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't an idiom, it applies the usual figurative meaning of ["push through"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+through) (force passage when it is hard) to a proof. As in [Hawkins, The Mathematics of Frobenius in Context, p. 265](https://books.google.com/books?id=UzTBBAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s):

> "*Frobenius was able to prove the answer was affirmative... but it turned out far more difficult for him to prove than the above proposition. To push through a proof he was forced to develop a “mod-$k$” analogue of his reduction theorem and its corollary on transformation to normal form for any positive integer $k$...*"